# Javascript: How to compare a string against an array of strings

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to check if a string is equal to any of the strings inside an array. I know you can check multiple parameters like so:

```
let value = 'sales';

if ( value == 'sales' || value == 'broker' ){}
```

But I need to use an array like:

```
let value = 'sales';
let array = ['sales', 'broker'];

if ( value == array ){}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: look for the index of the value in the array with `array.indexOf(value)`. It'll return `-1` if it's not found, or an index if it is. Note that `.includes()` might cause problems in Internet Explorer.

Comment: [].includes(value) .. [].some(x=>test(x)) .. `~[].indexOf(element)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
if (array.includes(value)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [array includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which returns a Boolean

```js
let array = ['sales', 'broker'];

function test( value ) {
  if ( array.includes(value) ){
    console.log('true', value)
  } else {
    console.log('false', value)
  }
}

test('sales')
test('world')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` function, which might be better especially if you later need some additional checks.

```
if(array.filter(el => el === value).length > 0){
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use includes method to check if array contains a value.

```js
let array = ['sales', 'broker'];
    
console.log(array .includes('sales'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use includes method

if (array.includes(value)) {
}